# DataGrid Row Removal Resulting in Error

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, user-controls

I have a datagrid that I programatically add a certain number of user control objects to in row definitions based on a user's selection. When the user selects a new option, I'm trying to clear each of the rows besides the header, but I keep finding that the last row definition ends up visually on the top of my header for some reason. Here's my code:

Here's where I add a row with the user control in it:

```
            For Each qTask As QTask In QBD.Tasks
                Dim rowDef As New RowDefinition
                rowDef.Height = New GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto)
                grdQBD.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef)

                Dim newTask As New QBDControls
                newTask.DataContext = qTask

                ...

                Grid.SetRow(newTask, grdQBD.RowDefinitions.Count - 1)
                Grid.SetColumn(newTask, 0)
                Grid.SetColumnSpan(newTask, 7)
                grdQBD.Children.Add(newTask)
```

Here's where I remove the rows (all but the first, my header):

```
    Dim rows As Integer = grdQBD.RowDefinitions.Count
    If rows > 1 Then
        For child As Integer = rows - 1 To 1 Step -1
            grdQBD.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(child)
            'I'VE ALSO TRIED .REMOVERANGE
        Next
    End If
```

[image: Here's the before]
[image: Here's the after]

Notice that the last row covers the header.

Comment: Care to let us know what the actual error is? And also perhaps let us know why you are trying to do this horrendous thing anyway... in WPF, I'm *sure* there's a *much* better way to achieve your *actual* goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your problem is that you are just removing the `RowDefinitions` and not the actual `UserControls`.

Since there is just one `RowDefinition` left, all `UserControls` will be in the remaining one, all on top of each other, with the last one added as the topmost one.

To get the behavior you want, I guess you have to remove the `UserControls` as well.

You can do that by looking through the children of the `Grid`, and removing the one with the current row index in the loop.

```
Dim rows = g1.RowDefinitions.Count

If rows > 1 Then
    For i As Integer = rows - 1 To 1 Step -1
        g1.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(i)

        ' Find the control in the row and remove it
        Dim controlToRemove = g1.Children.Cast(Of UIElement)()
            .Single(Function(c) Grid.GetRow(c) = i)

        g1.Children.Remove(controlToRemove)
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Your solution worked. I incorrectly assumed the controls were set inside the row and that deleting the row would also delete the control.